# MySQL - Php, returns "Unexpected end of input"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a *PHP* function that do the next steps:

```
$conecta = new Conexion();
   $sql = "SELECT `id_sala`, COUNT(`num_horas`) AS numero, `Fecha` FROM `registros_estudio` WHERE 1 GROUP BY YEAR (`Fecha`);"
    $r = $conecta->query($sql);
    $registros = array();
    while ($row = $r->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $registros[]= $row;
    }
    $conecta->close();
    return $registros;
```

It´s just a simple `SELECT` and it works fine, but when I change my *SQL* sentence to this

```
   $conecta = new Conexion();
$sql = "SELECT registros_estudio.id_sala, COUNT(num_horas) AS numero, Fecha, provincia_estado.nombre FROM registros_estudio, salas_estudio, provincia_estado WHERE salas_estudio.id_sala = registros_estudio.id_sala AND salas_estudio.provincia_estado = provincia_estado.id_provincia_estado GROUP BY YEAR (Fecha);";
    $r = $conecta->query($sql);
    $registros = array();
    while ($row = $r->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $registros[]= $row;
    }
    $conecta->close();
    return $registros;
```

This returns me an error like

> Unexpected end of input.

Both *SQL* sentences were tested and are working

Comment: there's a missing semi-colon at the end of your second line (but that's probably just a bad paste). Plus, `MYSQL_ASSOC` that should be `MYSQLI_ASSOC`

Comment: Why not `$registros = $r->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`.  No need for a loop to do what you're doing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah it´s a bad paste, btw the problem is in the sentence of the second code, thx for ur help

Comment: @Devon well this is not just mine, btw we have some other methods with `MYSQL_ASSOC` and they are working

Comment: That probably means MYSQL_ASSOC = MYSQLI_ASSOC but I wouldn't rely on a different API's constants.  However, my code wasn't about the MYSQLI as much as the loop.  fetch_all does exactly what you are doing with your fetch_array loop.

Comment: *"This returns me an error like "Unexpected end of input"."* - We need to know the exact error, including line number etc. and showing which one is the line. I'm doubting that what you posted, is causing this. Maybe a missing bracket/brace somewhere; who knows.

Comment: Where/how do you fetch that error message? I don't see exception catching code.